# MapStruct: List mapping is not using single mapping when annotated by @Named

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following Mapper

```
@Mapper
@Named("RoleBaseMapper")
public interface RoleBaseMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "code", source = "name")
    @Named("mapToBase")
    RoleGuiBaseDto mapToBase(Role role);

    @Named("MapListToBase")
    List<RoleGuiBaseDto> mapListToBase(List<Role> roles);
}
```

What I expect is that `mapListToBase` will use `mapToBase` to map each entry in the list. But when I see the generated code, I have the following

```
@Override
public List<RoleGuiBaseDto> mapListToBase(List<Role> roles) {
    if ( roles == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    List<RoleGuiBaseDto> list = new ArrayList<RoleGuiBaseDto>( roles.size() );
    for ( Role role : roles ) {
        list.add( roleToRoleGuiBaseDto( role ) );
    }

    return list;
}

protected RoleGuiBaseDto roleToRoleGuiBaseDto(Role role) {
    if ( role == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    RoleGuiBaseDto roleGuiBaseDto = new RoleGuiBaseDto();

    roleGuiBaseDto.setId( role.getId() );
    roleGuiBaseDto.setDescription( role.getDescription() );

    return roleGuiBaseDto;
}
```

A new mapper method is created and is used instead of using `mapToBase`.

How can I tell `mapListToBase` to use `mapToBase`.

NB : Things works well without `@Named`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to qualify the mapping method when using `@Named` (using `@IterableMapping#qualifiedByName`):

```
@Mapper
@Named("RoleBaseMapper")
public interface RoleBaseMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "code", source = "name")
    @Named("mapToBase")
    RoleGuiBaseDto mapToBase(Role role);

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "mapToBase")
    @Named("MapListToBase")
    List<RoleGuiBaseDto> mapListToBase(List<Role> roles);
}
```

Comment: Works well ! Thank you.

Comment: You can even leave out the `"RoleBaseMapper"` part in `qualifiedByName`. I updated the answer.