# MapStruct - working in one place but not the other

Tags: java, mapstruct

I've been having problems with mapstruct the last few days. It was supposed to be a simple job until something weird started happening.

I have BusinessUnit (BU) , UserBusinessUnitRole (UBUR) and Role.

UBUR has Role and BU. Role has BU. BU doesn't have anything.

I'm trying to map them. I've had UBUR successfully implemented for a lot of time. And cuz of changes in the Role I had to re-implement the role mapper (role didn't have a BU before that). So I start doing it and now I get a weird exception. I'll show first the BU mapper, entity and dto. Then the UBUR and finally the Role (with which I'm having problems)

BU Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "BusinessUnits")
public class BusinessUnit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private TypeName type;

    @Nullable
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CompaniesId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE)
    private BusinessUnit company;

    @Nullable
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ProjectsId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE)
    private BusinessUnit project;

    @Nullable
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "WhiteboardsId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Whiteboard whiteboard;

   //constructors, getters and setters
```

BU DTOs: (Each record is in a different file. Just put it one here to make the question "shorter")

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = BusinessUnitDTODeserializer.class)
public interface BusinessUnitDTO {

    Long id();

    String name();

    TypeName type();

    CompanyDTO company();

    ProjectDTO project();

    WhiteboardDTO whiteboard();

}

public record CompanyDTO(
        Long id,

        @NotNull
        @NotBlank
        String name,

        @NotNull
        TypeName type,

        @Nullable
        WhiteboardDTO whiteboard

) implements BusinessUnitDTO{

        public CompanyDTO company(){
                return null;
        }

        public ProjectDTO project(){
                return null;
        }

}

public record ProjectDTO(
        Long id,

        @NotNull
        @NotBlank
        String name,

        @NotNull
        TypeName type,

        @NotNull
        CompanyDTO company,

        @Nullable
        WhiteboardDTO whiteboard

) implements BusinessUnitDTO{

        public ProjectDTO project(){
                return null;
        }
}

public record TeamDTO(
        Long id,

        @NotNull
        @NotBlank
        String name,

        @NotNull
        TypeName type,

        @NotNull
        CompanyDTO company,

        @NotNull
        ProjectDTO project,

        @Nullable
        WhiteboardDTO whiteboard

) implements BusinessUnitDTO{
}
```

and finally Mapper:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {WhiteboardMapper.class}, collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.TARGET_IMMUTABLE)
@Validated
public interface BusinessUnitMapper {

    @Named("toBusinessUnitDTO")
    default BusinessUnitDTO toBusinessUnitDTO(@Valid BusinessUnit businessUnit) {
        return switch (businessUnit.getType()) {
            case COMPANY -> toCompanyDTO(businessUnit);
            case PROJECT -> toProjectDTO(businessUnit);
            case TEAM -> toTeamDTO(businessUnit);
        };
    }

    @Named("toBusinessUnitDTOs")
    default List<BusinessUnitDTO> toBusinessUnitDTOs(@Valid Iterable<BusinessUnit> businessUnits) {
        if(businessUnits == null){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return StreamSupport.stream(businessUnits.spliterator(), false)
                .map(this::toBusinessUnitDTO)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Named("toCompanyDTO")
    CompanyDTO toCompanyDTO(@Valid BusinessUnit businessUnit);

    @Named("toProjectDTO")
    @Mapping(target = "company", qualifiedByName = {"toCompanyDTO"})
    ProjectDTO toProjectDTO(@Valid BusinessUnit businessUnit);

    @Named("toTeamDTO")
    @Mapping(target = "company", qualifiedByName = {"toCompanyDTO"})
    @Mapping(target = "project", qualifiedByName = {"toProjectDTO"})
    TeamDTO toTeamDTO(@Valid BusinessUnit businessUnit);

    @Named("toBusinessUnitEntity")
    default BusinessUnit toBusinessUnitEntity(@Valid BusinessUnitDTO businessUnitDTO) {
        return switch (businessUnitDTO.type()) {
            case COMPANY -> toEntityFromCompanyDTO((CompanyDTO) businessUnitDTO);
            case PROJECT -> toEntityFromProjectDTO((ProjectDTO) businessUnitDTO);
            case TEAM -> toEntityFromTeamDTO((TeamDTO) businessUnitDTO);
        };
    }

    @Named("toBusinessUnitEntities")
    default List<BusinessUnit> toBusinessUnitEntities(@Valid Iterable<BusinessUnitDTO> businessUnitDTOs) {
        if(businessUnitDTOs == null){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return StreamSupport.stream(businessUnitDTOs.spliterator(), false)
                .map(this::toBusinessUnitEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Mapping(target = "company", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "project", ignore = true)
    BusinessUnit toEntityFromCompanyDTO(@Valid CompanyDTO companyDTO);

    @Mapping(target = "project", ignore = true)
    BusinessUnit toEntityFromProjectDTO(@Valid ProjectDTO projectDTO);

    BusinessUnit toEntityFromTeamDTO(@Valid TeamDTO teamDTO);

}
```

UBUR entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "UsersBusinessUnitsRoles", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"UsersId", "BusinessUnitsId", "RolesId"})})
public class UserBusinessUnitRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UsersId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BusinessUnitsId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE)
    private BusinessUnit businessUnit;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RolesId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Role role;
    
    //constructors, getters and setters
```

UBUR DTO

```java
public record UserBusinessUnitRoleDTO(

        Long id,

        @NotNull
        UserWithoutPasswordDTO user,

        @NotNull
        BusinessUnitDTO businessUnit,

        @NotNull
        RoleDTO role
) {

}
```

UBUR Mapper:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserMapper.class, BusinessUnitMapper.class, RoleMapper.class}, collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.TARGET_IMMUTABLE)
@Validated
public interface UsersBusinessUnitsRolesMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "user", qualifiedByName = {"toUserWithoutPasswordDTO"})
    @Mapping(target = "role", qualifiedByName = {"toRoleDTO"})
    @Mapping(target = "businessUnit", qualifiedByName = {"toBusinessUnitDTO"})
    UserBusinessUnitRoleDTO toDTO(@Valid UserBusinessUnitRole userBusinessUnitRole);

    List<UserBusinessUnitRoleDTO> toDTO(@Valid Iterable<UserBusinessUnitRole> usersBusinessUnitsRoles);

    @Mapping(target = "user", qualifiedByName = {"toUserEntity"})
    @Mapping(target = "role", qualifiedByName = {"toRoleEntity"})
    @Mapping(target = "businessUnit", qualifiedByName = {"toBusinessUnitEntity"})
    UserBusinessUnitRole toEntity(@Valid UserWithPassBusinessUnitRoleDTO userWithPassBusinessUnitRoleDTO);

    List<UserBusinessUnitRole> toEntity(@Valid Iterable<UserWithPassBusinessUnitRoleDTO> usersWithPassBusinessUnitsRolesDTOs);

}
```

And here comes the baffling part.

Role Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name= "RolesAuthorities",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RolesId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AuthoritiesId"))
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BusinessUnitsId")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE)
    private BusinessUnit businessUnit;

    //constructors, getters and setters
```

Role DTO:

```java
public record RoleDTO (
        Long id,

        @NotNull
        String name,

        List<Authority> authorities,

        @NotNull
        BusinessUnitDTO businessUnit
) {
}
```

Role Mapper:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {AuthorityMapper.class, BusinessUnitMapper.class})
@Validated
public interface RoleMapper {

    @Named("toRoleDTO")
    @Mapping(target = "businessUnit", qualifiedByName = {"toBusinessUnitDTO"})
    RoleDTO toDTO(@Valid Role role);

    List<RoleDTO> toDTO(@Valid Iterable<Role> roles);

    @Named("toRoleEntity")
    @Mapping(target = "businessUnit", qualifiedByName = {"toBusinessUnitEntity"})
    Role toEntity(@Valid RoleDTO role);

    List<Role> toEntity(@Valid Iterable<RoleDTO> roles);

}
```

I mvn clean before each "try".
And here's the problem. During compilation this line (`List<RoleDTO> toDTO(@Valid Iterable<Role> roles);`) throws two exceptions:

`java: The return type BusinessUnitDTO is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method.`

`java: Can't map property "BusinessUnit role.businessUnit" to "BusinessUnitDTO roleDTO.businessUnit". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "BusinessUnitDTO map(BusinessUnit value)".`

If I remove the mentioned line everything compiles.

1. The implementation is basically a for loop calling the single method n times
2. Pretty much the same thing works in the UBUR mapper

Why does it throw the exception on the list method and not the single one?
What is the problem? Why is it working in one place but not the other?

Also tried upgrading from mapstruct v1.5.3.Final to v.1.5.5.Final. Didn't help.

Found something (I think). MapStruct is going out of it's way to do what I don't tell it to do.
So I went into the implementations map struct makes. And I see what I expect from the UBUR mapper. Then I got into the Role implementation and see something weird

```java
protected BusinessUnit businessUnitDTOToBusinessUnit(BusinessUnitDTO businessUnitDTO) {
        if ( businessUnitDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        BusinessUnit businessUnit = new BusinessUnit();

        return businessUnit;
    }

    protected Role roleDTOToRole(RoleDTO roleDTO) {
        if ( roleDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Role role = new Role();

        role.setId( roleDTO.id() );
        role.setName( roleDTO.name() );
        List<Authority> list = roleDTO.authorities();
        if ( list != null ) {
            role.setAuthorities( new ArrayList<Authority>( list ) );
        }
        role.setBusinessUnit( businessUnitDTOToBusinessUnit( roleDTO.businessUnit() ) );

        return role;
    }
```

so the 2nd list method (dto to entity) calls roleDTOToRole which calls businessUnitDTOToBusinessUnit. The normal methods are calling their parent
so for some reason I'm telling mapstruct to use x method but it tries to create it's own implementation for some reason (instead of using the already created one) and miserably fails.

Ok it's cuz of the @Named annotation. Now just have to figure out how to tell mapstruct to not care about it.

Comment: The problem I was having and a solution are explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162518/mapstruct-list-mapping-is-not-using-single-mapping-when-annotated-by-named

Answer (score 1):

Have you explicitly mapped from `BusinessUnit` to `BusinessUnitDTO`? Try adding a method in `BusinessUnitMapper` to do this - that allows MapStruct to map `BusinessUnit` to `BusinessUnitDTO` when it encounters that type during the conversion from `Role` to `RoleDTO`. The explicit mapping should resolve the issue. Remember to do the same for the reverse mapping. If necessary, you can add a corresponding method to `RoleMapper`.

Comment: It's already implemented if you see the BusinessUnitMapper. (It basically just calls the correct method)